# call a custom observer in fuelphp

Tags: orm, fuelphp

i create a custom Observer :

```
class Observer_Test extends Orm\Observer 
{    
    public function after_insert(Orm\Model $model)
    {
        \Log::info('Succesfully created new object of class '.get_class($model));
    }
}
```

i put this code in `app/classes/observer/test.php`

and i called from my model in `app/classes/model/`
this my observer

```
protected static $_observers = array(
     'Observer\Observer_Test' => array(
           'events' => array('after_insert'),
     ),            
);
```

and i got an error message like this

> ErrorException [ Error ]: Uncaught exception 'Fuel\Core\FuelException'
>   with message 'Unable to create or write to the log file. Please check
>   the permissions on
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/MPOSSERVER/fuel/app/logs/' in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/MPOSSERVER/fuel/core/classes/log.php:77
>   Stack trace: #0 [internal function]: Fuel\Core\Log::_init() #1
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/MPOSSERVER/fuel/core/classes/autoloader.php(364):
>   call_user_func('Log::_init') #2
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/MPOSSERVER/fuel/core/classes/autoloader.php(247):
>   Fuel\Core\Autoloader::init_class('Log') #3 [internal function]:
>   Fuel\Core\Autoloader::load('Log') #4
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/MPOSSERVER/fuel/core/base.php(91):
>   spl_autoload_call('Log') #5
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/MPOSSERVER/fuel/core/classes/error.php(117):
>   logger(400, 'Error - Observe...') #6
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/MPOSSERVER/fuel/core/bootstrap.php(71):
>   Fuel\Core\Error::exception_handler(Object(UnexpectedValueException))

i think i wrong when i called or put the observer, what is the best practices for creating an observer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as I see, the error says that there is not enough permission to write to that directory, and observer itself is working. to make sure, just replace Log::() call with something like die('WORKS!'); instead.

To fix the problem, so the logs would start writing, try to fix the directory permissions. I'm not sure how MacOSX handles this but this might heenter code herelp you:

```
cd /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/MPOSSERVER

find . -type f -exec chmod 666 {} \;
find . -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
```

1st command will cd to you web project
2nd will make all files in that directory to chmod to 666 (read/write by everyone)
3rd command will make read/write/execute by everyone

Hope that helps
Good luck :)

Comment: You can also do $ php oil r install in the application's root directory to set all the needed file permissions.